# Enterprise package repository for angularjs/gruntjs app?

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs

What's a good option to release and manage angularjs apps? 
I mean, in java world, we have maven, in angular/grunt world we have yeoman/grunt, in java we have maven artifacts repos (archiva, atifactory or nexus), in angular/grunt world, we have what? A local npmjs could be a choice, but a angularjs webapps, doesn`t have a bin directory, or a executable you know?

Comment: Bower? http://bower.io/ It's not necessarily made of Angular.js apps, but client-side JS scripts/apps, CSS frameworks and others.

Answer (score 1):

I see Artifactory as a repo for artifacts/packages more than as a repo of full apps, and in those terms, bower.io seems to be the more appropriate answer: http://bower.io.